# random characters after the 64th on c++ mysql

Tags: c++, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm facing a very strange issue while interacting with mysql db through my c++ app.

environment:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'
services: 
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0.21 #libmysqlcppconn8-2_8.0.21-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb connector
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
        security_opt:
            - seccomp:unconfined
    client:
        build: .
        ports: 
            - "2890:2890"
```

Client container is ubuntu18.04, here a simple code to test connection and a minimum result:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <array>
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

int main() {
  sql::Driver *driver = get_driver_instance();
  sql::Connection *con =
      driver->connect("tcp://remote_backup_db_1", "root", "example");
  con->setSchema("db_test");
  sql::PreparedStatement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;
  stmt = con->prepareStatement("SELECT test from t;");
  res = stmt->executeQuery();
  if (res->rowsCount() > 0) {
    if (res->next()) {
      std::string text = res->getString("test");
      std::clog << "text: " << text << "\n";
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

here is a describe of the table:

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| test  | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**issue:** when I try to retrieve a text that is less than 64 bytes everything works properly, but when I try to execute the same code with a text greater than 64 bytes it retrieves the firts 64 bytes followed by random characters. The problem seems not to be related to the column type (same problem with blob for example). It seems to be related with encoding because when i try to get the result length, it is set properly (e.g with a 70 character text long it gives me 70).

I've already tried to change table encoding and I don't know how to solve this. (ps I'm not using strange characters only ASCII basically).

Comment: How did you put the text in the table?

Comment: @user253751 in the provided example by mysql console (handwritten) in the app through c++ code, both procedure same issue

Comment: Have you used a different tool to inspect the contents of the database and make certain that the data in the database was stored correctly?

Comment: @user4581301 yeah i made a simple select on db with mysql console after handwritten insert and c++ insert, in both case the content stored into db is the same that i've inserted